# Best way to reload image stored in Firebase Storage #askfirebase

Tags: firebase, ionic2, firebase-storage

I am creating an app using Ionic 2 and one of the features is to update your avatar. Typical stuff. When the user updates the avatar, the new one has to be downloaded.

How can this be done? Is there an event (re-get the image after the upload is complete) or do I just re-get the image after the upload?

Comment: Maybe you can add listener to the value of the avatar url for each user you fetch

Comment: I would need an event to let me know that the upload is complete

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the returned promisse of the method you called to save your new profile picture.

```
firebase.storage().ref('/ProfilePictures/').putString(MyPicBase64String, 'base64', { contentType: 'image/png' }).then((pic) => {
  let newPic = pic.downloadURL; // save in a new var, a global var, your sql/localStorage, the var in your <img />, etc 
});
```

If you need to do it separately, you can call `.getDownloadURL()` method

```
firebase.storage().ref('/ProfilePictures/MyUserNewPicture.png').getDownloadURL().then((pic) =>{
  // do your stuff
})
```